# Run A Script When Connected To A Wireless Network In Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, script

Is it possible to have a script run when I connect to a wireless network?

My university hijacks all HTTP(S) connections when you first connect to force you to log in with your university account. I've already written a script to take care of the log in, but I would like to have it run automatically when I connect to the network.

Comment: What script did you write to take care of the login?  I've been able to do this with lynx, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the Wicd network manager can do that. You might want to check it out, I know it work on ubuntu and opesuse

Answer (score 6):

Network Manager will automatically run scripts in certain directories at certain stages of network connection.

Loo in `/etc/network`. You'll see four directories, with self-explanatory names (given that "if" stands for "network interface"). You're looking for if-up.d. Put your script in there, name it something like `50-university-login.sh`, and *mark it executable*.

In case you're wondering, the numbered prefixes give the scripts an order. the "default" is 50, halfway from 01 to 99.

Comment: Old answer, but this doesn't work for me (anymore). I'm trying to run a script when (`wlan0`) connects to a hotspot. The script parses `iwconfig` and works when I manually call it.

I'm on Lucid and I symlinked my script into `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and it's never executed.

Any idea why?

Comment: Check this link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript
I had to do the second part, I guess I'm not using Network Manager